# Error adding new shard from mongos shell

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I'm learning setting up sharding in mongoDB, I plan to have 1 `configsvr`, 1 `shardsvr` and 1 `mongos`

I started the `mongod`s using

```
mongod --configsvr --replSet foo --dbpath e:\mongodb\configsvr --port 27019
mongod --shardsvr --replSet foo  --dbpath e:\mongodb\shardsvr --port 27018
```

I also connected to each `mongod`s using `mongo --port 27019` and `mongo --port 27018` and performed `rs.initiate()` on each

I so started the `mongos` using

```
mongos --configdb foo/MY-PC:27019
```

I finally connected to the `mongos` using `mongo` I got an error after using `sh.addShard('foo/MY-PC:27018')`

**Error**

```
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Cannot add foo/MY-PC:27018 as a shard since it is part of a config server replica set",
    "code" : 96
}
```

Please help to solve this error

Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set foo/MY-PC as a replica to another mongo server! it's data gonna be copy of that server!

**Replication** is **copying** a server's data in an other server so if something happen to it, you wouldn't loose your data! while **Sharding** is **breaking** your data into portions so you can speed up your data access speed by accessing different servers at the same time.

So if you shard your data in two portion Data-A and Data-B and your Primary replica server keeps Data-A, then foo/MY-PC would hold the same portion(Data-A) only!

Comment: I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/), for learning purpose how many `configsvr`s and `shardsvr`s are required ?, would you please help me correct the parameters I used to start the `mongod`s

Comment: If I were you, I would do **Replication** first and then **Sharding**! for sharding setup use different name to pass for --replSet (e.g foo1, foo2,...)! also check [this tutorial](http://codingmiles.com/mongodb-sharded-cluster-deployment/), it's more understandable.